# Google big query - split after dot and merge result

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to get a number of users with mobile operating system versions via google big query from Firebase dataset.

My input is:

```
Row versions users   
1   12.1.2  27984    
2   12.1    5702     
3   11.4.1  1354     
4   12.0.1  1325     
5   12.1.1  837  
6   12.0    685  
7   10.3.3  484  
8   12.1.3  411  
9   11.4    353  
10  11.3.1  184  
11  11.2.6  140
```

My desired output is:

```
versions users
12       34000
11       23000
10       10000
```

Basically, I want to know how many users use our 12, 11, 10,.. version. I don't mind about detailed versions.

Overall with my SQL skills I got here:

```
SELECT device.operating_system_version as versions, count(distinct(user_pseudo_id)) as users
FROM [my-table:analytics_188188188.events_20190102] 
WHERE device.operating_system = "IOS" and device.operating_system_version LIKE '10.%'
GROUP BY versions
ORDER BY users desc
LIMIT 1000
```

and it gives me nice results:

```
Row versions    users    
1   10.3.3  484  
2   10.2.1  53   
3   10.3.2  40   
4   10.2    31   
5   10.1.1  20   
6   10.3.1  18   
7   10.0.2  15   
8   10.0.1  5    
9   10.3    5    
10  10.0.3  2
```

But here, I don't know what I am supposed to do next. I can imagine that I have to do (somehow) to trim everything after the dot and then sum the number of users, but how to do it? Can you help me, please?

Comment: Be careful with `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` using legacy SQL. It won't give you exact results! Use standard SQL instead if you can. See also the [migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the major version.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(e.device.operating_system_version, '^[^.]*') as version,
       COUNT(DISTINCT e.user_pseudo_id) as users
FROM [air-bank-prod:analytics_188576439.events_20190102] e
WHERE e.device.operating_system = 'IOS' AND 
      e.device.operating_system_version LIKE '10.%'
GROUP BY version
ORDER BY users desc
LIMIT 1000;
```

Note:  For your particular example -- due to the `LIKE` condition -- you can just take the first two characters

```
SELECT SUBSTR(e.device.operating_system_version, 1, 2) as version,
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of extracting major version is as in below example - for BigQuery Legacy SQL (as it is what you use in your question)

```
#legacySQL
SELECT
  os, major_version, EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(user) users
FROM (
  SELECT 
    device.operating_system AS os,
    FIRST(SPLIT(device.operating_system_version, '.')) AS major_version,
    user_pseudo_id AS user
  FROM [my-table:analytics_188188188.events_20190102]
)
GROUP BY os, major_version
ORDER BY users DESC
LIMIT 1000
```

Note:
use of `FIRST(SPLIT(device.operating_system_version, '.'))` to actually extract major version
and
use of `EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(user)` to get distinct count of users

Also, consider [migrating](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql) your code to BigQuery Standard SQL as it is highly recommended by BigQuery Team (see comment by @ElliottBrossard)